# ElasticSearch Client vs Base JVM version

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jboss

I have an existing project that I want to use ElasticSearch in.
The core ElasticSearch requires Java 8, which isn't a problem since it will run in a different JBoss than the existing project we want to integrate with.

However, the ElasticSearch client will be integrated in the existing JBoss, which runs Java 7. Does anyone know the Java version requirement for the client? We are unable to upgrade this Java version due to other circumstances.

Comment: Hope [this answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-0-java-api-5-0-on-jdk-7/68222/2?u=avr) from elastic official community will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_java_virtual_machine.html) you can use 8 or 7, however 8 is preferred.

Comment: The guide you linked is called "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide [2.x]". Isn't this an outdated guide for 2.x versions? (current is 5.x)

Comment: This ia 2.x version of Guide, not Elasticsearch
2.x is "current"